# Two different buttons in one Panel in my own Component

Tags: java, netbeans, components

I'm trying to create JPanel with two different buttons which one of them increasing and second decreasing size of text or window. I have class with button declaration. Everything is working when I put these buttons on JFrame separately.
I don't know how to get Action Listener in JPanel of each buttons. All I possibly do is listener of mouse click on JPanel...
Could you help me? I'm really begginer with coding so be polite please :]

```
public class ButtonMy extends Component {
private ButtonIncrease increase;
private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;

public ButtonMy() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,30));
    kolor = Color.blue;
    setForeground(kolor);


    propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    increase = ButtonIncrease.Powieksz;

}   

public ButtonIncrease getIncrease() {
    return increase;
}

public void setIncrease(ButtonIncrease increase) {
    ButtonIncrease oldIncrease = this.increase;
    this.increase = increase;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("increase", oldIncrease, increase);
}

public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
    propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(l);
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
    propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(l);
}


}
```

There is JPanel for bind 2 buttons. Here is the biggest problem :/ I'm lack of ideas.

```
public class ButtonB extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

public ButtonMy b1 = new ButtonMy();
public ButtonMy b2 = new ButtonMy();

public ButtonB (){

    init();
}
public final void init(){
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    this.przycisk1.setIncrease(ButtonIncrease.Powieksz);
    this.przycisk2.setIncrease(ButtonIncrease.Zmniejsz);
    add(b1);
    add(b2);


}      

}
```

JFrame where I test this component is very common. Code below shows only function for inc and dec size when separate button is clicked (not in JPanel).

```
private void buttonMy3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    switch(buttonMy3.getIncrease()) {
        case Powieksz: setSize(1);
            break;
        case Zmniejsz: setSize(0);
            break;
    }
}
```

I didn't paste full of my code. There some of math functions left which I think they are not needed here (setSize for example).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understand the problem correctly but I think under the actionListener class you should have a method called actionPerformed& it will say that if button1 is clicked increase the number, if button2 is clicked decrease the number:

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) {
if (event.getSource()== b1) // your "increase size" code

if(event.getSource()== b2)// your "decrease size" code 
}
```

button listeners are actually different from mouse listeners; buttons implements  *ActionListeners* and have the *actionPerformed* method with *event* variable. you could handle the *event* by:
**getSource()** -this method is inherited from java.util.EventObject and returns the OBJECT on which the event initially occurred (the button itself)
or by **getActionCommand()** -this method is available to action events, or any event that inherits from ActionEvent and returns the command STRING associated with this action.
however mouse listeners implements *MouseListener* and has a lot of methods depending on what the mouse does (pressed, clicked, released, etc.).